# NodeJS program connection to MongoDB timeouts after opening MongoDB Compass

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas, windows-11, mongodb-compass

I am on a Windows 11 PC.
I am currently developing a NodeJS web server that uses MongoDB as a database.
My MongoDB Atlas is not hosted on the same machine I'm developing my web server on, but is instead hosted by MongoDB Atlas service.

The NodeJS program fully works, the connection to my MongoDB Atlas works fine, the problem is that whenever I open MongoDB Compass on my PC to modify some data on my db and at the same time I have my NodeJS server running locally, I connect to the DB through MongoDB Compass but my server stops responding and after 30 seconds ish it gives me a timeout error:
`Error: Error connecting to db: queryTxt ETIMEOUT`

Since I was connected to the database and my server works when MongoDB Compass is closed, I assume that the problem isn't in my NodeJS code, but here's the code that I use to connect to my db if it might help you:

```
const uri = process.env.MONGO_URI;
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");

client = new MongoClient(uri);

const DB = client.db("RBulk");
const usersCollection = DB.collection("user");

//After this I use the collection to get and add data
```

Note that the URI is correct in my .env file since I'm able to connect until I open MongoDB Compass.

The problem is that after I open MongoDB Compass, even if I both close MongoDB Compass and restart my NodeJS program, my NodeJS program doesn't work properly anymore until I restart my PC.

Note that I can connect to my database with MongoDB Compass when I don't have the NodeJS program running, but whenever I get the timeout error on my program and restart MongoDB Compass I then can't connect anymore to my db from MongoDB Compass.

Is there a way I can fix this so that when I open MongoDB Compass my program doesn't break?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `queryTxt ETIMEOUT` is a DNS error.  I'm not sure how opening compass could cause a timeout querying DNS.